Сводная таблица excel
Задача: создать сводную таблицу, добавить вычисляемые меры.
Источник данных - несколько плоских таблиц.
Как правильно добавить меры так, чтобы они легли отдельными строками в сводной таблице и рассчеты велись для каждого класса и возможно ли извернуться так впринципе?


Вот есть такая инструкция вот можно по этой инструкции сделать это

Спасибо за комментарай.
Но в статье ответа на мой вопрос, к сожалению, нет.

тогда могу предложить импортировать данные из других таблиц в другой лист а на нужном просто привязать данные к ячейкампример
